# Ubuntu pygame gets event.key values

Tags: python, pygame, ubuntu-18.04

The following **pygame** code stopped working correctly after I upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print "KEY:", event.key
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            # The code here is executed when "Esc" is pressed.
        elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
            # Never happens even when "f" is pressed.
```

The code prints "`Key: 193`" when I press `f` instead of expected "`Key: 102`".

Any ideas what can be wrong?

I have several keyboard layouts installed and I am sure that I use "English" when it happens.

Comment: The scancode `193` belongs to the symbol `KP_F` in SDL, which is *Keypad F*. Do you have and use an alphanumeric keypad? Since it's rather rare, pygame is missing theses constants.

Comment: If not, it's most likely because your keyboard layout.

Comment: I checked the layouts. It does not matter which layout I use, the results is always 193. The other characters also generate wrong keys.
I do not have alphanumeric keypad.

Comment: What kind of keyboard are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that your keyboard configurations haven't changed since the Ubuntu version change, then you can solve this issue by comparing unicode values:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print "KEY:", event.key
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            # The code here is executed when "Esc" is pressed.
        elif event.unicode == 'f':
            ...
```